# Read in CSV file in Python differ from Uipath: Line-by-line loop needed?

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python. I used to use Uipath to read in CSV files and extract certain information using regex expression.

However, when I tried in Python I get error "NoneType object has no attribute 'group'", which mean a match is not found.

But my regex expression works fine in Uipath.

**Python Code:**

```
      text_lines=f.readlines()
      model_regex=re.compile(r'(?<=model choice :).*')
      model=model_regex.search('text_lines')
      print(model.group())
```

1. do I have to place my variable (text_line) in quotation marks here?

```
model=model_regex.search('text_lines')
```

2. I basically open a csv file and read it all the text using

```
text_lines=f.readlines()
```

But will text_lines look exactly like in the csv file? I noted when I use print(text_lines), all the lines look jumbled up.

3. Is there a way to read in text_lines to look exactly like in the csv files so that my regex expression work?
4. Or is it for Python , I need to loop line by line of the text_lines to look for the regex expression?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.read_csv?`

Comment: Hi, I solved the issue. Whether for read.csv or readlines, each line of the csv file is saved as an element in a list. To make each line look as in the csv file, use join to join all elements in the list. Wonder why nobody told me that. Thanks